# Check for usage of json key

Tags: javascript, json, react-intl

I have a json file that I use across a couple of related code repositories (it is a language file for use with `react-intl`)

It's grown substantially over time (several hundred keys), and we're wanting to tidy it up.

Is there any quick sane way to identify if any of the keys are unused?

the file looks like this:

```
{
  "Account.AdditionalInformation": "Additional contact information",
  "Account.Address": "Address",
  "Account.Billing": "Billing details",
  "Account.BillingName": "Billing name",
  "Account.BillTo": "Bill to",
  "Account.BillTo.Company": "A company",
  "Account.BillTo.Me": "Me",
  "Account.CompanyName": "Company name",
  "Account.CompanyMember": "has added you to their corporate account",
  "Account.Department": "Department",
  "Account.Email": "Email address",
  "Account.EmailVerified": "Thank you for verifying your email!",
  "Account.EssentialContact": "Essential contact details",
  "Account.FamilyName": "Surname",
  "Account.GivenName": "First name",
  "Account.JobTitle": "Job title",
  "Account.Phone": "Phone number",
  "Account.Sector": "Industry sector",
  "Account.Title": "Title",
  "Account.Title.Female": "Mrs",
  "Account.Title.Male": "Mr",
  //.. and so on 
}
```

Comment: No, there is no simple way. Lets imagine that keys are builded dynamically, e.g. `'Account.' + 'Family' + 'Name'`. If you look in source code for `Account.FamilyName` it will be hard to find if process like that has been placed

Comment: Most of the keys aren't built dynamically - the formatting is just to impose some sort of order to the chaos that is json ;) There are a couple of keys like "Order.Dialect.en-uk" where the last part is variable but they'd be easy to spot in any review

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and use `hasOwnProperty` to check if this object have any key by this name.Prior to this you need to get the content of the json file in a variable

```js
var myJSON = {
  "Account.AdditionalInformation": "Additional contact information",
  "Account.Address": "Address",
  "Account.Billing": "Billing details",
  "Account.BillingName": "Billing name",
  "Account.BillTo": "Bill to",
  "Account.BillTo.Company": "A company",
  "Account.BillTo.Me": "Me",
  "Account.CompanyName": "Company name",
  "Account.CompanyMember": "has added you to their corporate account",
  "Account.Department": "Department",
  "Account.Email": "Email address",
  "Account.EmailVerified": "Thank you for verifying your email!",
  "Account.EssentialContact": "Essential contact details",
  "Account.FamilyName": "Surname",
  "Account.GivenName": "First name",
  "Account.JobTitle": "Job title",
  "Account.Phone": "Phone number",
  "Account.Sector": "Industry sector",
  "Account.Title": "Title",
  "Account.Title.Female": "Mrs",
  "Account.Title.Male": "Mr",
  //.. and so on 
}

function checkKey(keyName) {

  if (myJSON.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) {

    alert(keyName + " Exists")
  }
}
checkKey('Account.Address')
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I actually need to go deeper and search through the source code for each of those keys. For example a form might have something along the lines of ```<Field
                component={TextField}
                name="familyName"
                label="Account.FamilyName"
                validate={required}
                showErrorBeforeTouched
              />```